# How to convert with gzsdf in Gazebo 1.2.5?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Could I get an example how to convert an sdf 1.0 to sdf 1.2 with the gzsdf tool?

gzsdf convert [sdf_file] when I run it like this:

*$./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert /home/<some_path>/models/spatula.sdf*

gives me this *ERROR: SDF parsing the xml failed*

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/412/how-to-convert-with-gzsdf-in-gazebo-1.2.5?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out, I did not *$source setup.bash* in the gazebo folder.

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on 2013-02-01**:
it didnt work.
john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ source setup.bash
john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert /home/john/fuerteworkspace/sandbox/miurdf/01-myfirstyo.urdf

Error: Unknown option[convert]

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-04**:
Can you post your SDF file?